# Problems with QScript

Tags: c++, qt, qtscript

It’s all the day that I’m trying to make this code working. It should be the same code presented in the QScript [help page](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/scripting.html#prototype-based-programming-with-the-qtscript-c-api) but unfortunately it doesn’t work at all!

```
class Person
{
public:
 QString nm;

 Person()
 {

 }

 Person(QString& name)
  :nm(name)
 {

 }
};

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Person)
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Person*)

QScriptValue Person_ctor(QScriptContext* c,QScriptEngine* e)
{
 QString x = c->argument(0).toString();
 return e->toScriptValue(Person(x));
}

QScriptValue Person_prototype_toString(QScriptContext* c,QScriptEngine* e)
{
 Person* per = qscriptvalue_cast(c->thisObject());
 qDebug(qPrintable(per->nm));
 return e->undefinedValue();
}


....
 QScriptValue per_ctr = eng->newFunction(Person_ctor);
 per_ctr.property("prototype").setProperty("toString",eng->newFunction(Person_prototype_toString));
 per_ctr.property("prototype").setProperty("myPrint",eng->newFunction(Person_prototype_toString));
 eng->globalObject().setProperty("Person",per_ctr);
...
```

If I try to evaluate the following code in JavaScript

```
var p = new Person("Guido");
p.toString();
p.myPrint();
```

I should obtain:

```
Guido
Guido
```

instead what I really obtain is a white string from the toString function (probabily is calling the Object.toString function) and a “Interpreter Error: line 2: TypeError: Result of expression ‘p.myPrint’ [undefined] is not a function.” error message from myPrint. I suppose that I didn’t connect correctly the two functions to the Person prototype even if I tried to follow litteraly the documentation pages…PLEASE Could someone explains me what is my fault?!? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

what happens if you remove the brackets after toString and myPrint?

Comment: if I remove the brackets

var p = new Person("Guido");
p.toString;
p.myPrint;

I have no error messages but I have not 

Guido
Guido 

like I was expecting but an empty string...

Comment: return e->toScriptValue(Person());
shouldnt it be
return e->toScriptValue(Person(x));
?

Comment: thanks for the notification! unfortunately it is not the problem... :( it continues to act in the same way (white string from toString and error message from myPrint)

Comment: how about 
qDebug() << qPrintable(per->nm);
looks like qDebug() is a constructor
http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qdebug.html#QDebug-2

Comment: f I try to check the presence of the property myPrint from the C++ side with
per_ctr.property("prototype").property("myPrint").call();
the function is called (even if it clearly crashes because it’s not called on a valid object). But this means that at least in the c++ side of the application the myPrint function exists in the Person’s prototype. I cannot say the same thing in the JavaScript side when i get an Interpreter Error: line 2: TypeError: Result of expression ‘v.myPrint’ [undefined] is not a function.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't:

```
Person* per = qscriptvalue_cast(c->thisObject());
```

be:

```
Person per = qscriptvalue_cast(c->thisObject());
```